# FLEX F5 Refresh event handler does not work in IE8?

Tags: apache-flex

I have an issue in handling the F5(Refresh) option in IE8 using FLEX. As i got some code by surfing..which is as follows

public function handleKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent) :void
   {
    display.text = "Key was pressed: " + event.keyCode;
   }
  ]]>

The main intention of the code is to handle F5(refresh) event. It works fine in Mozilla, GoogleChrome but not in IE8. When i execute the code in IE8 before the event handle by the FLEX the browser is handling the event. So kindly let me know if there is any solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how that code you showed will do anything to the browser, or anything special with the F5 key.

I suspect that your problem is a focus issue.  I have found that in Firefox (my main browser), if a Flex movie is selected, I cannot use control-T to open a new tab.  Yet, if I click into the address bar or some other "non-flex" portion of the page, the new tab opens without any problems.  I believe it is because once the Flash Player has focus, the key commands do not get sent to the browser.

I suspect the same issue is happening with IE8. and the F5 / refresh key.  I do not have a solution for you.